# Python Component Logic - Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I am trying to create a responsive web app using python. My backend is written in python and the GUI is made using streamlit library.

My goal is to get the information from GUI and save them to a database.
Since streamlit runs top to bottom whenever there is a change in the GUI, I am not quite sure what is an elegant solution for my problem.

My problem:
Whenever the user pushes the submit button after changing the form components, the information becomes their initial values in the first run.
I mean if the initial values were set to something, I got those when form submit button is clicked.
I want to get the last values of the components when form submit button is clicked so that I can save those to database. Any advice?

```
Some code here.

with st.form(...):
  x = st.selectbox (with some initial value)
  y = st.text_input (with some initial value)
  z = st.multiselect (with some initial value)

_ = st.form_submit_button(label="Submit", on_click=on_click_labeling_button, args=[<some arguments here>]

some code here..
```

Rephrase:
When "on_click_labeling_button" is called because of the callback, I get the initial values of x,y,z. Not the ones that the user is changed them to.

Is there a way to get the last values from those components in any way?

Comment: You need to add statefulness to your app: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state

Comment: When you say "Is there a way to get the last values from those components in any way?", do you mean the values of x, y and z from your sample code?

Comment: Well, yes, but I don't want their initial values. The problem is, when on_click function is called (let's say the first time), user inputs are delayed until the next internal execution because the values of x, y and z are already set at that point.

Comment: Statefullness is good and all but when I implemented that, unfortunately the same problem still occurs.